Are the oscillations of a transverse in a plane parallel or perpendicular to the waves direction? (Wording Problem)
This is the question that prompted my confusion

FYI. The question number on the left is 3.
I was under the impression that this is the correct answer:

But the correct answer was this?

Is my logic wrong?
Or is the question wrong?

What is a "direction of oscillation polarized light" mean? Do you mean the electric field, the magnetic field, both? If we're constraining it to a plane, then polarization doesn't matter, nor which field we're talking about, and none of the planes you have drawn is correction.
